# Disable Hardware Lock Elision

Tags: x86, icc, intel-tsx

I am trying to make the profit of Hardware Transactional Memory [TSX] visible in a little application. The compiler automatically uses Hardware Lock Elision [HLE] for Mutexes which is not what I want at that point. Is there a way to disable automatic Hardware Lock Elision on a Haswell Processor using icc?

Google and Intel documentation did not help so far.

Comment: Not sure about this, but glibc has a flag `--enable-lock-elision=yes`. That might work if you don't pass it or pass it as `no`? https://github.com/andikleen/glibc/blob/rtm-devel9/README.md . Some discussion here: http://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2013-06/msg01048.html

Comment: Thanks for those links, but as I understand them it is is not possible to enable and disable them at different compiler actions with any parameters. so I can have one or the other, but not compile one program with and one program without HLE

Comment: @Henkersmann Hi, it's an old post but is there any chance you managed to disable HLE? Similarly, I want to compare performance with and without transactional memory optimizations.